# Archive checked records in grid view (Change 0 to 1 in database)

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a grid view which pulls through data dictated by a stored procedure.

[image: screen shot 1]

The stored procedure is called GetEverything.
The statement is made up of information from 2 tables, one with person detail, and one with vessel detail. The stored procedure select statement contains the following Where clause:

```
WHERE Vessel.ArchiveStatus = 0
```

By default, every new record that is created using the front end application is given a '0' for ArchiveStatus in the db.

So, the gridview will only show me the records where the ArchiveStatus is 0, which by default is evertything.

The 2 boxes, Check All and Uncheck All are working fully.

What I need now is when a REF or REF(s) are selected and the button 'Archive Records' is clicked, for the 0 in the database to be updated to a 1 for that VesselREF.

Can anoyone advise how to do this and give me some example code to put in the Default.aspx.vb file/ Event Handler for the archive records button.

With this is place, the grid view will only display the non-archived records, and I can create a seperate grid view with its own SQL to bring through the archived records.

```
GridView.aspx

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="REF,VesselREF" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="132px" 
        style="text-align: center; font-family: Calibri; font-size: medium" 
        Width="508px" BackColor="#C4FFC4">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REF" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="REF">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="Details.aspx?REF=<%# Eval("REF")%>"><%# Eval("REF")%></a>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RecordSelector" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" 
                SortExpression="Surname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VesselName" HeaderText="VesselName" 
                SortExpression="VesselName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VesselREF" HeaderText="VesselREF" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="VesselREF" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you show also the aspx markup of the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `TemplateFields` and you want to use your stored-procedure to set both archived states:

```
Protected Sub btnArchive_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles btnArchive.Clicked
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ChkRef"), CheckBox)
        If (chk.Checked) Then
            Dim refID As Integer = Integer.Parse(row.Cells(5).Text)
            ArchiveRecord(refID, True)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ArchiveRecord(refID As Integer, archive As Boolean)
    Using con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefID", refID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Archive", archive)
            con.Open()
            Dim affectedrecordCount As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I need this in vb if possible?

Comment: In the New sqlConnection(), im assuming I delete what you have in here and put my own connection, how do i reference what is contained in the web.config file?

Comment: @SelectDistinct: I've assumed that you use [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx). Here's a tutorial that shows how to read from the web.config file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411(v=vs.100).aspx Remember that you also need to change all of my variable names(f.e. `LblVesselRef`) which i didn't know.

Comment: Since i've only just seen that you've added the aspx part, i've edited my answer again to show how to read the values. **Edit**: Have you added the connection string to the  connectionStrings section or to the applicationSettings settings?

Comment: Between :-
<connectionStrings> and  </connectionStrings> in the web.config file

Comment: Then use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ABCconnectionstring").ConnectionString`

Comment: Now it does not like 'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure' it says "Command Type is not declared"

Comment: Intellisense should help you. `CommandType` is an enumeration in the `System.Data` namespace. So either import it on class/project level or use the full path: `cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the GridView.DataKeys property and store the row ID value for each DataKey.
Then, when you update, enumerate through the GridViewRows and use FindControl to locate the CheckBox.  Then you check if the box is checked and if so, concatenate to a string...

```
' on update_pressed()...
Dim Ids as new StringBuilder()
For each gvr as gridViewRow in myGv.Rows
   Dim cbx as CheckBox = gvr.FindControl("myCheckBoxID")
   if cbx.Checked Then
      Ids.Append(gvr.DataKeys(gvr.RowIndex).Value.ToString & ",")
   End If
End For
' Ids now contains "5,6,87,356,2355," etc
```

You can then use a SQL CSV to Table Variable function to put the Id values into a table variable to work with